# MySQL LEFT JOIN two tables using max and other parameters from second table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Have these tables and need to join them to create a final list.

```
accounts
-----------------------------------------------------
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY         | ACCOUNT_OWNER      |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | bmw             | 100                |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2          | audi            | 100                |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 3          | mercedes        | 100                |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 4          | porsche         | 200                |
-----------------------------------------------------

users
--------------------------------
| USER_ID    | NAME            |
--------------------------------
| 100        | bob             |
--------------------------------
| 200        | sally           |
--------------------------------
| 300        | mark            |
--------------------------------

log_type
--------------------------------
| TYPE_ID    | TYPE            |
--------------------------------
| 1          | sales           |
--------------------------------
| 2          | follow up       |
--------------------------------
| 3          | marketing       |
--------------------------------


logs (logs for each account)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| COMPANY_ID | TYPE            |  USER     | DATE          | NOTE         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2               |  200      | 2014-06-05    | 123          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2               |  100      | 2014-06-03    | ABC          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2               |  100      | 2014-06-01    | 789          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 3               |  100      | 2014-06-01    | XYZ          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2          | 3               |  100      | 2014-01-01    | Hello        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2          | 2               |  100      | 2014-01-01    | Hello        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

WANT THESE RESULTS
- Show table of accounts from one user (in this case bob).
- Show the last log attached to the account. (If none present then show anyway/NULL)
- Only pull logs that are of type 'follow up' ( (log_type.TYPE = 2)
- Sort the list by the oldest attached logs first. (logs.DATE asc)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| COMPANY    | TYPE            |  USER     | DATE          | NOTE         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| audi       | follow up       |  bob      | 2014-01-01    | Hello        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| bmw        | follow up       |  bob      | 2014-06-03    | ABC          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| mercedes   | NULL            |  bob      | NULL          | NULL         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Current code looks like this....

```
select c.COMPANY, lt.TYPE, u.NAME, l.DATE, l.NOTE from accounts c 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON c.ACCOUNT_OWNER = u.USER_ID 
  LEFT JOIN logs l ON ( (c.ID_COMPANY = l.COMPANY) && l.TYPE = '2' && u.USER_ID = 100
  LEFT JOIN log_type lt ON l.TYPE = lt.TYPE_ID 
  WHERE u.USER_ID = 100 && l.TYPE = '2' 
  GROUP BY c.COMPANY_ID
  ORDER BY l.DATE asc
```

Comment: soo..what doesn't work?

Comment: The only way to get this result would be a `UNION` with either a hardcoded 'bob' or a hardcoded 'mercedes'.